# Why is there a hole in the large surf board (6075)?

Tags: piece-information

Why does the large surf board (part 6075) have a large hole in it? The hole is larger than a normal stud. An example of this part is found in red in Coast Guard Starter set (60163):

[image: 60163]

Here's a closeup of the board so that you can specifically see the large hole that I'm asking about:

[image: 6075 surf board]

Comment: A picture of the large hole in question would be nice.

Comment: @EJMak Good call. I've added that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This part is sometimes used to build a windsurfer as shown in Stephanie's Beach House:

[image: 41037]

The hole is larger than a stud because it is designed to receive a towball connection of some kind, usually a mast such as this one:

[image: 6076]